# Does service gets restarted automatically after an application is manually force closed from settings screen

Tags: android

I am testing one scenario where i have to test whether the application service gets restarted after an application is manually force closed from settings screen.

When i force close the app in logs it shows:-

06-30 11:26:30.283: WARN/ActivityManager(116): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.test.app/.comm.PushService in 5000ms

But the service never gets restart after a 5sec.

I have override all necessary methods in the service(returns START_STICKY in onStartCommand).

What am i missing..?. Help Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your service is a part of application. So in case if you kill the application all the dependent processes will be killed as well(if its done through Android's Task Manager.I think if process killed through any of the Task Killers in Android market the service gets restarted again).

Comment: i am talking about force close case from settings screen > Manage Application > Force Close.

Comment: Yes in that case it will not restart. I also had some time to do RnD through this scenario and came to a point that if we Force Close the app then service will not restart.

Comment: so is this there any solution on it, some Service FLAG to be added instead of START_STICKY..

Comment: There can be one case in which you can do it but isnt feasible for every application. You can make an application that solely includes Service. And another application that has your front end. Both interact with each other through Broadcasts. Then only your service will close only if user goes to settings => running service and tap to close. And closing your application will not effect it.

Comment: @samrad i thing it is not the good idea to do that.Thanks for the help.